# My recursive function seems to be using the original list instead of creating a new one in python

Tags: python, recursion

I'm pretty new to python and I've been trying to write a minimax algorithm for tic-tac-toe. But I can't get my program to return the expected value and I'm not sure what's going on. My minimax method should be returning 1, but instead pretty much broken. I believe it's using the original list instead of creating a new one. I tried using copy() but it didn't work, unless I used it wrong. Here is my code:

```
import copy

def checkWin(board):
    if board == [['y', 'x', 'y'], ['x', 'y', 'x'], ['x', 'y', 'x']]:
        return 't'
    if board == [['y', 'x', 'y'], ['x', 'y', 'x'], ['x', 'x', 'y']]:
        return 'y'
    return '0'
    
def minimax(board, player):
    status = checkWin(board)
    if status == 't':
        return 0
    if status == 'y':
        return 1

    if player == 'y':
        value = -100000
        for i in range(3):
            for k in range(3):
                if board[i][k] == '':
                    board2 = copy.deepcopy(board)
                    board2[i][k] == 'y'
                    bestMove = minimax(board2, 'x')
                    if bestMove > value:
                        value = bestMove
        return value
                    
    else:
        value = 100000
        for i in range(3):
            for k in range(3):  
                if board[i][k] == '':
                    board2 = copy.deepcopy(board)
                    board2[i][k] == 'x'
                    bestMove = minimax(board2, 'y')         
                    if bestMove < value:
                        value = bestMove

        return value

board = [
            ['y', 'x', 'y'],
            ['x', 'y', 'x'],
            ['x', 'x', '']
        ]               
bestMove = minimax(board, 'y')
print(bestMove)
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Edit. Thanks to the people who helped, I'm sorry I'm such an idiot. But I will make sure to learn how to debug my programs more carefully and thoroughly.

Comment: "My minimax method should be returning 1, but instead pretty much broken. ". Please define "broken". Is it throwing an error? Is it simply returning something other than 1? If the latter, what *is* it returning?

Comment: Sorry I should have clarified, I get this error over and over,                                       `File "minimax.py", line 24, in minimax
    bestMove = minimax(board2, 'x')`, but it has different line numbers each time and it ends in this error, "RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object"

Comment: Have you done any debugging? I would recommend reading https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Comment: `RecursionError` means `minimax` never stops calling itself

Comment: Well I'm not very good at coding so I've been trying to fix it on my own for the last few hours, and I honestly can't think of the correct solution. Normally I would debug it on my own, but I'm starting to get desperate. Sorry, if this question wasn't a very good one, but I will check out the link you have included. Thanks.

Comment: If you suspect that your copy isn't working, why have you not tested that idea?  Print values and check the id's.

Comment: How much of this program *have* you tested?  Can you reduce those parts to simple value assignments?  At this point, you should be able to "accuse" the 5 lines (or fewer) that were your last update.

Comment: "I'm not very good at coding" All of us started somewhere. Keep working at it. Be sure you also learn how to debug code. The link from Eric Lipper's blog linked earlier is a good place to start. As a professional programmer, I use the techniques described there every day. Debugging is one of my most invaluable tools. I almost never get my code right the first time.

Answer (score 1):

You want to assign value not compare `board2[i][k] == 'x'` should be `board2[i][k] = 'x'` same with y.

```
import copy

def checkWin(board):
    if board == [['y', 'x', 'y'], ['x', 'y', 'x'], ['x', 'y', 'x']]:
        return 't'
    if board == [['y', 'x', 'y'], ['x', 'y', 'x'], ['x', 'x', 'y']]:
        return 'y'
    return '0'
    
def minimax(board, player):
    status = checkWin(board)
    if status == 't':
        return 0
    if status == 'y':
        return 1

    if player == 'y':
        value = -100000
        for i in range(3):
            for k in range(3):
                if board[i][k] == '':
                    board2 = copy.deepcopy(board)
                    board2[i][k] = 'y'
                    bestMove = minimax(board2, 'x')
                    if bestMove > value:
                        value = bestMove
        return value
                    
    else:
        value = 100000
        for i in range(3):
            for k in range(3):  
                if board[i][k] == '':
                    board2 = copy.deepcopy(board)
                    board2[i][k] = 'x'
                    bestMove = minimax(board2, 'y')         
                    if bestMove < value:
                        value = bestMove

        return value

board = [
            ['y', 'x', 'y'],
            ['x', 'y', 'x'],
            ['x', 'x', '']
        ]               
bestMove = minimax(board, 'y')
print(bestMove)
```